Response.End(), CompleteRequest(), and return
Background:
In an old code base I'm working on, we have a funky structure with the way our API calls get called, meaning we route through aspx pages first. So to make a typical API call out to a different service, we would typically make a POST request to a url such as "app/items/updateitem.aspx" which would then make a call like var updatedItem = await itemServiceApi.UpdateItem(...list of params) and then write out the result like so: Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedItem).
My question is related to error handling in an aspx endpoint like this and what the proper way is to stop code execution.
Question:
If the above code were placed into a try-catch statement, for example:
try {
    var updatedItem = await itemServiceApi.UpdateItem(...list of params);
    Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedItem);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(...log params here);
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    // what to put here? return? Response.End() 
    // HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()?
}

//possibly more code, but not necessarily

What are the behavioral differences between simply returning, calling Response.End(), or calling CompleteRequest()?
I understand that Response.End() will throw the ThreadAbortException and isn't preferred to be used, but I'm struggling to see a difference of benefit between calling CompleteRequest() and simply returning to stop code execution on the code-behind page.

If you simply return, then the page will be rendered as usual.

@MichaelLiu The aspx page itself has no content to be rendered, it only serves as an endpoint to call out to an external API. We pair these endpoint pages with a JS front-end for most of our rendered pages.

you can use a response.flush() and no error will be triggered.
